# how to execute a .sql script on heroku?

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

I have a .sql file with a bunch of insert commands that I want to execute on my postgres database on heroku. But I don't know how to do it:-

If I had access to postgres console I'd type the following:

```
psql -h localhost -d database -U username -f datafile.sql
```

but it seems that heroku doesn't support this command. I've tried with

```
heroku pg:psql
```

but that doesn't let me input a file.

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

For things like seeding a database, I recommend Richard Brown's answer:  you're arguably better off using something like Rails seeds mechanism, or something scripted like a rake task.

That said, being able to pipe sql (raw, or a file) is a useful feature, especially for idempotent things like simple look ups or routine queries. In which case you can execute your local sql with any of the following:

```
$ cat file.sql | heroku pg:psql --app app_name
$ echo "select * from table;" | heroku pg:psql --app app_name
$ heroku pg:psql --app app_name < file.sql
```

Comment: Little note, the `--app app_name` is not required. I run `heroku pg:psql` from the directory my heroku app is located and it detects the app name. Besides that, this works great!

Comment: @levibostian A git repo can be connected to multiple Heroku apps thourgh

Comment: @leo you may be right and you may be wrong, I am not sure. I have not used heroku is a handful of years. I can no longer help this question or my comment.

Answer (score 25):

Why not just use psql?

If you look at the output of `heroku config` you will see the database URLs (DATABASE_URL key) your application is using - if you take this and break them apart in to the correct bits for using with the `psql` all will be good.

eg

```
DATABASE_URL:  postgres://username:password@host:port/dbname
```

becomes

```
psql -h host -p port -d dbname -U username -f datafile.sql
```

Comment: I am getting the error: `FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host ...`

Comment: make sure you are using SSL for the connection - may require `&ssl=require` on the connection string.

Comment: Now, `psql postgres://username:password@host:port/dbname -f datafile.sql` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

I like updates that are testable and repeatable.  When I need to update the database I write a rake task to perform the update; that way you can run it against test first to guarantee the output is correct before running in production.

You don't mention if this is an initial database load or one run later, but the convention for loading fresh data into a Rails database is to create a `db:seed` rake file that you can execute after your `db:migrate` task is done.

See: http://justinfrench.com/notebook/a-custom-rake-task-to-reset-and-seed-your-database
And: http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data

Comment: The link says:  _"A custom Rake task to reset and seed your database" you're looking for has been removed_

Comment: That happens to old links.  Archive.org to the rescue: http://web.archive.org/web/20130312172900/http://justinfrench.com/notebook/a-custom-rake-task-to-reset-and-seed-your-database

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest another approach, since I was already benefited from this question and I looked for **better** options to do that (in terms of speediness).

I conditioned the database seeding to an environment variable. With `Sequelize` is going to be something like this (the code bellow is only to demonstrate the conditioning):

```js
// Node.js app
if (process.env.RESTARTDB) {
  sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    // "init" is a raw SQL query
    sequelize.query(init);
  });
}
```

This method is **not recommended** if you don't want to restart your app every time you want to query that `SQL` file, but it is so much faster than doing by using `heroku pg:psql`.

[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars) you can find more info on **how to config your vars**.