# SQL visual client to query a databse deployed at heroku

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, model

I know Heroku has [a command line client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237366/how-to-execute-a-sql-script-on-heroku) to execute a `.sql` file.

But is there something like an SQL Server Management Studio for databases deployed at Heroku? I was looking for a UI that allows you to interactively write queries, execute them, and view the results on a grid. I'll mostly execute SELECTs and UPDATEs based on ids, over databases generated by Rails.

Comment: TADA look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769860/connect-to-a-heroku-database-with-pgadmin how to do it with pgadmin

Comment: Also, Valentina Studio: http://www.valentina-db.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.pgadmin.org/ and install pgAdmin III. I use it for the same purpose, watch and query over the database of one of my Heroku apps.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Adminium: it's a free control panel plugin for Heroku.

https://addons.heroku.com/adminium